# What is the correct way to install python on OS X?

Tags: macos, python

Im learning python programming, what is the correct way to install python on Mavericks 10.9?. Is it correct just to download the installer or use homebrew instead to install python?.

Answer (score 6):

OS X Mavericks actually ships with Python in `/usr/bin/python`:

```
|ruby-2.1.1| mymachine in ~
○ → /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

You don't need to install Python at all to get started developing with Python on OS X. That version is sufficiently high enough to be useful for Python 2.x development work and not totally suck (i.e. it's not Python 2.4).

My personal preference to is to use Homebrew for installing command line tools. You get a nice, neat, compartmentalized installation that's fairly straightforward to wipe away if it bothers you. So, I would use Homebrew to install a newer version of Python if I wanted it.

To install Python with Homebrew first install Homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then install Python 2.7.8 with:

```
brew install python
```

As you can see, this is the 2.7.8 version of Python:

```
|ruby-2.1.1| mymachine in ~
○ → brew info python
python: stable 2.7.8 (bottled), HEAD
http://www.python.org
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1 (4976 files, 81M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/python.rb
```

If you'd also like Python 3.4.1 you can use:

```
brew install python3
```

Which you can see gives you:

```
|ruby-2.1.1| mymachine in ~
○ → brew info python3
python3: stable 3.4.1 (bottled), HEAD
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/python3.rb
```

Homebrew will install any dependencies you need to run Python in either case.

Comment: I need to install python 2.7.8. So do you recommend me to install it with homebrew?, Why?.

Comment: Yes. Use Homebrew.

Comment: But if i use brew install python how to specify python 2.7.8 version?

Comment: You get the latest 2.7.x by default. I'll update the post with details in a bit.

Comment: But the latest is Python 3.4.1, how to install the 2.7.8 version?

Comment: See answer. The `python`package in Homebrew *is* Python 2.7.8.

Comment: @anon see my answer

Answer (score -2):

Download the source code like `Python-3.4.1.tgz` or whatever version you are looking for from Python official website and extract it:

```
tar -xzf Python-3.4.1.tgz
cd Python-3.4.1
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Installing from source code can be done in other platforms like Linux.

Verify the installation by:

```
bash-4.3$ python
Python 3.4.1 (default, Aug  4 2016, 13:53:56)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Do you ever confirm the validity of a tar archive with a hash supplied by developer? Or, read the INSTALL and README's  within the extracted archive? Or, use `./configure -h` to see what your install options are?

Comment: I installed the tar off python website

Comment: Why not the compiled version from the same place?

Comment: if you are talking about the dmg it doesn't work on El Capitan. I have written a question that explains that http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248330/installing-python3-4-1-on-osx-el-capitan